# Why does this command work when inputted directly, but results in an error within a script?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

When I try this command in Ubuntu Terminal:

`gcloud dns record-sets update test.pixelcraftserver.net --rrdatas=<MyIPAddress> --type=A --zone=pixelcraft`

It works perfectly fine, however in a bash script using multiple commands, it doesn't work at all giving this error:

Script:

```
IP_ADDR=$(curl ifconfig.me)
gcloud dns record-sets update other.pixelcraftserver.net --rrdatas=$IP_ADDR --type=A --zone=pixelcraft
gcloud dns record-sets update test.pixelcraftserver.net --rrdatas=$IP_ADDR --type=A --zone=pixelcraft
gcloud dns record-sets update main.pixelcraftserver.net --rrdatas=$IP_ADDR --type=A --zone=pixelcraft
```

Error:

```
' does not exist.s.record-sets.update) HTTPError 404: The 'parameters.managedZone' resource named 'pixelcraft
' does not exist.s.record-sets.update) HTTPError 404: The 'parameters.managedZone' resource named 'pixelcraft
' does not exist.s.record-sets.update) HTTPError 404: The 'parameters.managedZone' resource named 'pixelcraft
```

Any help on this matter would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you try to add the parameter `--project=<YourProjectID>` to your commands? You might not load the command in the same context and you haven't the same exact parameters.

Comment: Another issue you will have is that you must start your update with `gcloud dns record-sets transaction start` and finish with `gcloud dns record-sets transaction execute`.